# What does "running at both ends" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does "running at both ends" mean vomit and diarrhea at the same time? Is this a common usage? I can't find this usage in the dictionary.

I read this from the book [*Dirty Chinese*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1569757275). I doubt its correctness, so I opened this question to confirm.

> Man, that poor bastard has got no luck at all. Between the booze and the diarrhea, he's **running at both ends.**

[image: A screenshot of the English text with Chinese below it]

Comment: @danhekun Thanks. Could you please also type out that text into the question so it's searchable? I could only do the English part, but not the Chinese. I don't think the pronunciation guide is relevant, so feel free to leave that out

Comment: @gotube haha I'm not able to type the Chinese characters. I hope someone who knows Chinese could help to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is figurative language, used for effect.  It's not a very common idiom or well known phrase. It does mean, in context, that he has diarrhoea and is vomiting. For example, [here is another use of the expression.](https://www.valvereplacement.org/threads/diarrhea-and-nausea-med-interaction-with-coumadin.20336/)

The use of "running" to mean "allowing a liquid to flow" is standard.  "I left the tap running." And this is just a development of that meaning - with the intent of creating a phrase that is grotesque, funny, and impactful.

This may be a literal translation of the Chinese idiom, or at least an attempt to preserve some of the flavour of the Chinese - this book is for English speakers learning Chinese, not for Chinese speakers learning English. It's correct, meaningful and understandable in English.